# QGIS plugin FilterLayersAtOnce

Tags: qgis

Can someone please direct me to a tutorial relating to the QGIS plugin [FilterLayersAtOnce](https://github.com/muratkendir/FilterLayersAtOnce). I want to filter multiple layers at the same time if the layers has a common attribute table value.